# JS chart library for multi color bar

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm looking for a JS library to build a chart multi-colored bars.
I'm not talking about about different colors for each bar, but two or three colors on the same bar.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time comparing Javascript charting frameworks and would recommend [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).  It's the most complete JS charting library out there.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I had a look in the HighCharts website, but I didn't find a way to make charts multi-colored bars, is that possible ?

Comment: Yep, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5sGy/1/ - this shows one unique color but each column/bar could be unique.

Comment: What I need is two color on the same bar, not bar of different color, do you know what I mean ? thanks for your help btw

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by two colors, do you mean "stacked" column charts?  You can also do gradients on a single column.

Comment: English is not my mother language, and you actually just give me the word: 'stacked'! I found on HighCharts website how to build that type of chart, thank you so much!

Comment: Stacked bar charts are pretty standard charting library fare. [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com), [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com), etc.